Reading the picture changes on FOSS photo editing software
As the name of the topics says, I am looking for the FOSS photo editing software, who can read the picture changes and adjust its settings accordingly.
It should work that I provide original image, than edited image, and software will read what changes were made, adjust its own settings accordingly so I can then export that settings and create a preset.
I am pretty sure that Darktable or Rawterapee had something similar, but I can’t find it now.
I want to recreate my presents from Lightroom that way and move my edits to FOSS.
Thank you for any suggestions

Do I understand correctly that you want to provide an original file (e.g. a raw file) and a version that has been processed with a different software and from that want to infer settings in the new software to achieve the same result?  I don't think that this will ever be possible in a reliable manner as different softwares use different algorithms, so they may not be able to reproduce each other exactly.  That said, as long as your Lightroom presets only do global adjustments (i.e. no local changes like sharpening), you could create a lookup table (LUT) based on it...

... This LUT could then be used in the other application (I think both darktable and rawtherapee support LUTs).

For darktable, there is also darktable-chart, maybe that's what you had in mind?  I think it has the same limitation of not supporting local operations, though.

thank you guys. Yes, you both got what I meant. The darktable-chart is what I have been looking for

The go-to site if you are in FOSS photography: https://discuss.pixls.us/c/software/9. The devs of most majors FOSS apps hang out there.
